# What sort of test do I need to validate my form alter?

Tags: 8, testing

I have written a `hook_form_alter` and added a custom validation callback for the term edit form.
Then I have added custom validation to taxonomy term name length. This is the callback code:

```
/**
 * Validation callback function.
 */
function max_length_error_message($form, FormState $oFormState) {
  foreach ($form as $field) {
    $field_name = $field['widget']['#field_name'];
    if($field_name == 'name'){
      $value = $oFormState->getValues()[$field_name][0]['value'];
      $strLength = strlen($value);
      if($strLength > 60) {
        $oFormState->setErrorByName('name', t('@fieldname cannot be greater than: "@maxlength" characters.',
          ['@fieldname' => 'Practice Space name ', '@maxlength' => 60]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, can I write a test case around this code or do I need to wrap my code inside a class first and then write the test case?

Comment: Is this a case for validation constraint instead of a form alter? That would make it testable. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint

Comment: At least that seems proper to me, even in a simple case like this. By adding a Constraint, that would ensure that no matter where the taxonomy term is added, it adheres to the same rule. With form alters, you're attaching this handler to different instances. Some modules open up more than one way to add a term to the UI, just food for thought.